# HTML comments in Spark view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

How can I comment out parts of a Spark view so they aren't rendered to the client?

In aspx pages I can do this:

```
<%-- server-side comment --%>
```

I had thought using three dashes would work:

```
<!--- server-side comment --->
```

but it doesn't work and I now can't find the resource where I read that.

Comment: What if you used: `#//comment`?

Comment: That would do but I was hoping for a more 'HTML-ly' like way of doing it, especially for commenting out large blocks.

Comment: `#/* comment ... more lines ... # */` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use

```
# /* 
   Comment
   Goes
   Here
# */
```

(**EDIT**) Better yet, just use ASPX style tags:

```
<title> Hello World <% /* comment 
        goes here */ %> </title>
```

And, of course, HTML comments always work, too, if you don't mind seeing the commented text in your source.

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda funny, I couldn't find either.
I looked into the source code of spark, in the parsing area. I found the [code grammar parse](http://github.com/loudej/spark/blob/master/src/Spark/Parser/Code/CodeGrammar.cs) which is I assume applicable to code blocks. In there you should be able to use //. Then in the [markup grammar](http://github.com/loudej/spark/blob/master/src/Spark/Parser/Markup/MarkupGrammar.cs), the only mention of commenting is the standard HTML commenting (`<!-- -->`).